# Migrating SP 2007 web parts to SP 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to migrate web parts that were created in 2007 to 2010, the problem i have is i didn't use VSeWSS when i created these. All the files in the web part project i have is here...

[image]

My question is, is there a better way of migrating these?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, treat them the same as any other webpart created in sharepoint? you can use a .wsp solution package and put your webpart in it from what I remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want full SP2010 support? In that case, create a new SharePoint solution in VS2010 for SP2010, and import your existing webpart classes and files. The only thing you need to do next is update all SharePoint version numbers from 12.0.0.0 to 14.0.0.0.

(and after that, fix some issues because some things works different in SP2010).